# Linux Bash POST values to PHP

Tags: php, bash, post, drupal, curl

I used to have a Linux Bash Script that got values from the host computer (for example the computer serial number) and then POSTed that value to a Drupal node create form value.

For the life of me ; i can not remember how I did it.  I think that I used curl with the value in the curl command which sent that.  The bash script  would have gotten the value form the host system and sent in the the form of a POST to the php form.  That php form had a variable to receive the POST and then use the variable as a substitute in the 'value' fields.

Can anyone refresh my memory on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use curl

for example:

```
curl --data "key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3" http://domain/file
```

Comment: So you need it as a PHP script or in BASH? 
In php you normaly get $_POST['key1'] etc. when you call curl.

Comment: No the bash I have.  It is pretty much as you said. But the bash script is posting to a php form.  I haven't got the php form correct.

Comment: Then you need to post a snipped of the php code, it is hard to say anything without it. All the values from curl you can read as $_POST, probably some additional value like "form=true" where form is a $_POST key is need to trigger the php form.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Your first comment was enough to refresh my memory.  I knew I had done it previously.  Its always the simple things.....